# GaussianMatrix algorithm details

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing, reference-request

`GaussianMatrix[]` supports a `Method -> "Bessel"` option which the documentation describes (in the Details section) as:

> With the default option setting `Method->"Bessel"`, `GaussianMatrix[r]` has elements proportional to $\prod_{i=1}^2 \text{exp}(-\sigma^2)I_{x_i}(\sigma^2)$, yielding a kernel with optimal discrete convolution properties.

Does anyone have a reference to a paper or other explanation for this kind of window function/kernel design, that explains in which sense this has optimal discrete convolution properties? Basically i want to understand the theory behind it so i can design other kernels in a similar manner.

Comment: Have you seen these [two](https://people.kth.se/~tony/papers/cvap66.pdf) [papers](https://people.kth.se/~tony/papers/disc-der-approx-Njet.jmiv93.pdf) by Lindeberg?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive Thank you very much! This scale-space theory for discrete signals looks exactly like the hint i was hoping for! I'll dig into the theory of it and then hopefully be able to derive a proper discrete Airy disk kernel with it :) Also i would accept this if you post it as an answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe later, when I have time to write a good executive summary of Lindeberg's stuff. Alternatively, if you manage to write a summary of those papers, you could answer this question yourself. ;)